# Задний фон при скроллинге страницы

Tags: html, css, прокрутка, background

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Салют, фиеста! Есть задний фон в браузере, рисунок досок. Как мне сделать так, чтобы при добавлении информации на страницу изображение подгружалось вместе с контентом? То есть, при скроллинге страницы фон оставался всегда, а не так, как на скриншоте. Это какое-то свойство css контейнера? В HTMLbook ничего похожего не нашёл к сожалению. И можно ли это сделать как-то проще, без включения сюда JS? Пример контейнера с подключением картинки указал ниже.

```css
body {
    background: url(imgs/background_page.png) no-repeat;
    -moz-background-size: 100%;
    -webkit-background-size: 100%; 
    -o-background-size: 100%; 
    background-size: 100%; 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поставьте для background-size значение "cover", а значение "fixed" для background-attachment сделает картинку неподвижной при скроле. В любом случае, попробуйте поэкспериментировать со значениями, чтобы найти более оптимальный для себя вариант.

```
body {
    background: url(imgs/background_page.png) no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, нашёл для себя то что было нужно! Галочку Вам.

Answer (score 0):

Можешь поставить размеры body в 100% :)

```
.page {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: добавил к теку body класс page, использовал ваш код, не помогло :(

Comment: И было бы неплохо увидеть html сам. Есть ещё свойство такое background-size: cover; . Можно его попробовать.